# when using SimpleModal and open an Iframe it is calling the src twice

Tags: iframe, simplemodal

I am using SimpleModal and i am opening an Iframe (using ff)
it seems to work ok in ie9 but in ff it is calling the iframe src twice

Thanks for any help

the code i am calling looks like

```
function addNew(){
    var src = "/php/ftp/parsehome.php?dir="+userDir+"&idx=new";
    $.modal('<iframe src="' + src + '" height="445" width="800" style="border:0">', {
          containerCss:{
              backgroundColor:"#E1EFF7",
              borderColor:"#00A99D",
              height:450,
              padding:0,
              width:840
              },
              modal: true
           });
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by calling the frame src twice?

Comment: I am having the same problem. I don't know why it calls the define src of the iframe two times instead of just one. It calls it, and then calls it again

Comment: Same problem here. Any progress on this?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. Looking at the plugin code...

```
// add styling and attributes to the data
// append to body to get correct dimensions, then move to wrap
s.d.data = data
    .attr('id', data.attr('id') || s.o.dataId)
    .addClass('simplemodal-data')
    .css($.extend(s.o.dataCss, {
        display: 'none'
    }))
    .appendTo('body');
data = null;
```

You can see the `data` is added to the page body with the line `.appendTo('body');` to calculate the correct dimensions for the modal. If you comment out this line, it will prevent the iframe being called twice.

```
// add styling and attributes to the data
// append to body to get correct dimensions, then move to wrap
s.d.data = data
   .attr('id', data.attr('id') || s.o.dataId)
   .addClass('simplemodal-data')
   .css($.extend(s.o.dataCss, {
      display: 'none'
   }));
data = null;
```

Not sure if this modification will cause your modal size to have the wrong dimensions, but my iframe was set to `width=100%` and `height=100%` so didn't affect me.